# between date inteval mysql not showing today

Tags: mysql, sql

my query:

```
SELECT p.idprd, 
       p.nmprd, 
       pe.idprd, 
       pe.stockjual, 
       pe.stockkeluar, 
       pe.tothrgjual, 
       pe.tgljual 
FROM   tbproduk AS p 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idprd, 
        Sum(stockjual)   AS 'stockjual', 
        Sum(stockkeluar) AS 'stockkeluar', 
        Sum(tothrgajual) AS 'tothrgjual', 
        tgljual 
    FROM   tbpenjualan 
    WHERE  '2019-01-06' >= '2019-01-06' - INTERVAL 7 day 
    AND '2019-01-06' < '2019-01-06' + INTERVAL 7 day 
    GROUP  BY idprd
) AS pe ON p.idprd = pe.idprd
```

my result

[image: my result query]

my data:
[image]
date '2019-01-06' not showing. how to my currentdate to showing

Comment: The where clause looks weird. You are not comparing it to any field. Remove it and you will have the exact same result.

Comment: @ibu: how is query where 'tgljual' = 2019-01-06 is showing

Comment: Your query does not contain `'tgljual' = 2019-01-06`. Maybe you should add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY has missing column - which would prevent you to even execute SQL statement successfully. But after adjusting SQL statement, results include correct sets of data.

```
SELECT p.idprd, 
   p.nmprd, 
   pe.idprd, 
   pe.stockjual, 
   pe.stockkeluar, 
   pe.tothrgjual, 
   pe.tgljual 
FROM   tbproduk AS p 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT idprd, 
       Sum(stockjual)   AS 'stockjual', 
       Sum(stockkeluar) AS 'stockkeluar', 
       Sum(tothrgajual) AS 'tothrgjual', 
       tgljual 
   FROM   tbpenjualan 
   WHERE  '2019-01-06' >= '2019-01-06' - INTERVAL 7 day 
   AND '2019-01-06' < '2019-01-06' + INTERVAL 7 day 
   GROUP  BY idprd, tgljual
) AS pe ON p.idprd = pe.idprd 
ORDER BY pe.tgljual desc;
```

**Query Result**:
[image: SQL Query result snapshot]

Comment: oke. But, I want data "idprd" in single row, sum "stockkeluar" and "tothrgjual"